# Why does yahoo movies return an "unknown issue" page?

Tags: java, request, screen-scraping, limit, yahoo

As I know yahoo movies doesn't have an API, I made a scraper (Java) for it. 
Now the problem is that as I'm requesting several pages to yahoo movies, it sometimes return an **"unknown problem"** page so I decided to re - request the page until it shows the page with the info that I want but sometimes I have to re -request like 20 times, 40, 120, 400 so that's not fine :(   .
I'm pretty sure that i'm requesting the correct url.
Here is an example url

http://movies.yahoo.com/mvc/dfrv?mid=1810159162&uid=vdpL427zgsScLbwOEsyG4zOn1bQex.F2Xg--&s=&i=0&spl=0

So I go through its pagination.

Does somebody knows why is this happening? Is yahoo limiting?

Also, do you know other source or API to get movie reviews? (apart from IMDB)

Thanks

Comment: *"I made a scrapper"*  Maybe the code is just angry & seeks attention.  Try giving it Valium.

Comment: `why dows yahoo movies return an “unknown issue” page?` - If we knew, it wouldn't be an _`unknown issue`_, would it?

Comment: `I have to re -request like 20 times, 40, 120, 400 so that's not fine ` - apparently, yahoo are of the exact same opinion :)

Comment: There is an api for movies, it's called YQL.

Answer (score 2):

First, check that this is acceptable by their TOS. They might not appreciate their site being scraped.

Second, I would assume they are throttling your connections. Rather then trying again until it works, I would throttle it yourself. Consider a `Thread.sleep(500)`. (Tweak the number such that you don't get an error.) If you consistently show up as throttled, they're likely to just block your IP.

Comment: It's unlikely Yahoo would return 'unknown issue' for being scraped. They would more likely give a message explaining what they're doing and why.